# Difficulties using $in with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get all fields present in mongodb. I am using mongoose and I have used `$in` but when check mongoose log query it is sending wrong parameters

```
projectkeywordModel.find( { keywordId: { $in: id } } );
```

but query is passing in monggose like below:-

It works with single Id

```
projectkeywords.find({ 
  keywordId: { '$in': [ '53bcc3cb7d538efefbe55f98' ] } 
})
```

but when there is more than one id in array then its not working

```
 projectkeywords.find({ 
      keywordId: { '$in': [ '53bcc3cb7d538efefbe55f98', '53bcc3bd7d538efefbe55f96' ] } 
    })
```

here is my Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId=mongoose.Schema.ObjectId;


var ProjectKeyword = new Schema({
  projectId: String,
  keywordId: String,
  developerId: String,


}, {
  versionKey: false,

  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true,
    transform: function(doc, ret, options) {
      ret.id = ret._id.toHexString();
      delete ret._id;
    }
  },

  toObject: {
    virtuals: true
  }
});

module.exports=mongoose.model('ProjectKeyword', ProjectKeyword);
```

Comment: When you use the `$in` operator, you need to pass an array of values. What exactly is the issue here? Is the problem the fact that it is converting your `id` argument to a string? What type of object is the `id` argument?

Comment: the id will be a objectId, I suspect you are passing the wrong values

Comment: Id here is list of id in array

Comment: Mongoose "autocasts" ObjectId values, but it depends on what is in the schema. So what is the "schema" definition used by this model? Please add the schema definition to your question.